# Vapor's crypto.json - deployment-safe?

Tags: swift, encryption, vapor

I see in `vapor`, there's this `crypto.json` as part of any project created with `vapor toolbelt`

```
{
    "hash": {
        "method": "sha256",
        "key": "password"
    },
    "cipher": {
        "method": "chacha20",
        "key": "passwordpasswordpasswordpassword",
        "iv": "password"
    }
}
```

Should any of that be updated for deployment?

Comment: @JamesKPolk vapor is a web framework for swift. How do I make keys - any rules to their length ?

Comment: Regarding length, each cipher/hash has its own requirements. You'll get an error message if you use an invalid length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, definitely don't deploy your application with the default cipher or hash keys. There are two solutions to this.

## 1: Secrets Folder

You can do this easily by providing a `crypto.json` in the `secrets` folder.

`Config/secrets/crypto.json`

```
{
    "hash": {
        "method": "sha256",
        "key": "<16 characters>"
    },
    "cipher": {
        "method": "aes256",
        "key": "<32 characters>"
    }
}
```

The `Config/secrets` folder is in the `.gitignore` by default and should never be committed to version control.

## 2: Environment Variables in Config

If it is difficult to add a `Config/secrets/crypto.json` file to your production server, you can instead use environment variables.

`Config/production/crypto.json`

```
{
    "hash": {
        "method": "sha256",
        "key": "$HASH_KEY"
    },
    "cipher": {
        "method": "aes256",
        "key": "$CIPHER_KEY"
    }
}
```

This file doesn't contain the keys and could safely be committed to version control.

Just make sure you are running your app with `--env=production` (which you should already be doing for many other reasons, including performance)

Comment: So I'd assume I'm to put something like this to key: `openssl rand -base64 30 | cut -c1-16` and `openssl rand -base64 30 | cut -c1-32`

Comment: What are these keys used anyways?

Comment: I've restarted the server, there seems to be no error messages. How do I verify that correct values are used from `secrets/crypto.json` ?

Comment: Ok, I can kinda verify that correct values are available by reading output of this in the log: `drop.log.error("secrets \(String(describing: drop.config["crypto"]))")`

Comment: The interesting thing is that you mentioned that methods has key length requirements, however app perfectly starts and there's no error message if I set a key with incorrect length (e.g. 30 instead of 32 for `aes256` and 15 instead of 16 for `sha256`).

Comment: that sounds like a bug. mind reporting it to github.com/vapor/vapor?

Comment: Just so that I understand, are those `cipher` / `hash` used internally by `vapor` (e.g. for `TLS`) or are those to be used by user?

Comment: they are used for `drop.hash.make()` and `drop.cipher.encrypt()/decrypt()`. TLS uses it's own ciphers depending on the connection and configuration.